# How to model social graph in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, modeling

Very simple scenario

N users, each user can have 0 .. N - 1 friends (who are also users)

How can I model this in *Java* for AppEngine data store

Scenario to consider

- user x and user y become friends (so both need update their own status, in a transaction

Answer (score 7):

We've modeled user relations as a simple UserRelation entity:

```
class UserRelation {
  User _from;
  User _to;
  RelationState _state;
}
```

Where RelationState is an enum, describing states (normally, there is more than friendship)

```
enum RelationState {
  BLOCKED, NONE, PENDING_FRIEND, FRIEND;
}
```

Actually, we also use this enum for authorizaton, e.g. on user profiles.

```
enum RelationState implements IRole {
  BLOCKED, NONE(BLOCKED), PENDING_FRIEND(NONE), FRIEND(PENDING_FRIEND);

  private final List<IRole> _impliedRoles;
  private final List<String> _roleStrings;

  private RelationState(final IRole... impliedRoles) {
    HashSet<IRole> set = new HashSet<IRole>();
    for (final IRole impliedRole : impliedRoles) {
      set.add(impliedRole);
      set.addAll(impliedRole.getImpliedRoles());
    }
    _impliedRoles = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<IRole>(set));

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(getImpliedRoles().size() + 1);
    list.add(getName());
    for (final IRole implied : getImpliedRoles()) {
      list.add(implied.getName());
    }
    _roleStrings = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
  }

  public List<IRole> getImpliedRoles() {
    return _impliedRoles;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name();
  }

  public boolean hasRole(final IRole role) {
    return this == role || _impliedRoles.contains(role);
  }

  public List<String> getRoleStrings() {
    return _roleStrings;
  }
}

public interface IRole {
  public List<? extends IRole> getImpliedRoles();
  public String getName();
  public boolean hasRole(final IRole role);
  public List<String> getRoleStrings();
}
```

It's easiest to have two objects for each (symmetric) relationship (e.g. friendship as used on facebook) and only a single object for non-symmetric relationships (e.g. followers as used on twitter or blocked users). While this might look like overhead in the first place, using two objects certainly simplifies querying.

I think the AppEngine part itself should then be pretty straight forward.

Comment: This is a great idea and gives me much more flexibility.

My original thought was something align to the following 

class User {
  Long id;
  Set<Long> friends;
}

for which I had hard time to figure out the relationships (self-referential) and how to represent them, and also worry about the transactional cost.

I still need to consider using transaction when doing updates, but it's more clear and tangible.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `Friendship` table with just two foreign keys, `user1` and `user2`. An entry in this table models an social connection between two users. You could even add more columns to describe the `type` of this social relation.

(or consider sfussenegger's answer ;) same idea but better presentation)