# Social Graph Assignment

Tags: graph, social-networking

I have a Social Graph assignment, and I have a pretty good idea of what I want to do, I just want to know if I'm on the right track, and any hints you guys can provide.

Anyway, fairly simple implementation (I found a very complex one here - [How to model social graph in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138329/how-to-model-social-graph-in-java), but I think it's far more than what I actually need). Essentially my idea is to make a "User" object and a hashmap to keep everything in. A User object will have 4 data structures within it - name (string), student (boolean), school (string), and friends (integer array).

Each user will be added to the hashmap, and thus given a unique key. When a friendship is to be made, say between A and B, I go to the user A in the hashmap and ad the key for user B into A's friends array, and vice versa. That way I can keep track of everyone and who they're friends with.

Does this make sense? It works out in my head, but I feel like I'm missing something in the implementation that will make this not work as well as I think it should.

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track. The data structure and subsequent approach will be the same approach more or less regardless of language. If you are looking for additional ideas, remove your focus of Java and see what you find.

Comment: Thank you, I have removed the references to Java to try and get more general responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this will depend on the requirements and what you want to do with your social graph (especially on whether you want to persist the data or not).

If you are using a hashmap as your user store, then I assume you have a separate class that is generating your ids (or you have a UserStore class that wraps the hashmap and generates them)?  If you are not deleting users, then you could suffice to have an ArrayList as you store, with the index being the user key.

When it comes to the users themselves, you could hold their friends in a List, but that may complicate your delete user code slightly (assuming you have that functionality).

UPDATE:

If you want to do analysis, then you may get some benefit from storing a User's friends as a Set<"UserKey"> instead of as an array (but depends on how you plan to do your analysis).  You would still need a counter class (or master UserStore class that assigns the ids).

Comment: I don't need to delete any users, the rest of the assignment involves analyzing for things like cliques (groups of friends that aren't friends with others) and that kind of thing, but I'm trying to work out the best way to store the data first before I begin working on the algorithms to analyze it. I decided to use a gashmap because of the efficiency of pulling keys and values in and out, so that I can search for a user and get back their key quickly, then search to see if anyone is friends with that user using that key (hope that made sense).

Answer (score 0):

I would add some form of "primary key" to the User object, a number that might be sintetic (taking the next number from a global integer counter). This way, you can avoid the situation of generating a hashCode() value from the other User's data, and then you can avoid collisions inside the Map.

Comment: I guess you could imply that the OP was going to generate the key from the data however they did specify unique, _thus given a unique key_.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, when I instantiate a new User object, they should immediately be given a key from a counter, so the first user created gets 1, the second user gets 2, etc.

Then, when adding these users to the hashmap container, I should use the User object as the value, and this key I've given them as the hashmap's key. Is this correct?

Comment: That's right. Since you said that somebody's friends is represented as an array of integer values (which would be the key of the user into the hash table), so unless you have a fool proof way to come up with a hashing function that does not generate collisions, then a simple global counter is a simple solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it can work.

The only thing you're missing for sure, is that adding a `User` to a `HashMap` does not "give" it a key. The key should be created by you somehow. You can choose the user's first name, last name or to generate an incremental id. You add the `User` to the `HashMap` by giving it that key and the `User` as the value. You'll have to use that key each time you want to retrieve that `User` from the `HashMap`.

In your case, if first and last name are unique, use `firstName + " " + lastName` as the key.

There are many other recommendations that widely depend on the expected usages of the model. So, I don't see a reason to get into all of that.

Comment: Thank you very much! My expected uses are basically analysis of the graph, such as who is friends with whom, and a kind of 6 degrees of Kevin Bacon where I have to find the shortest distance between two people. All of that, I think, is algorithmic, but I wanted to have a stable base of how I'm storing the information before I begin to analyze it.